# Question word ellipsis

Tags: questions, ellipsis

> じゃあんたはなりたいか

Is this the same as じゃあんたは何になりたいか but with 何 implied?
I'm thinking it might be like in English where a teacher might say to a child "and you want to be ...?" with rising intonation, expecting the child to complete the sentence by saying "a doctor" for example.

Comment: It never hurts to include some context.

Comment: Unfortunately, the amount of context I'd need to add would be rather large. Please see comment below the current answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't sounds to me like there would be an implied 何 there. I think it means just literally "well then, do you want to become [one]?"

Would be easier to say for sure with some context about the conversation, i.e. were they talking about becoming something specific before that.

Comment: It's a conversation about two different kinds of people. The quote above is from the narrator. It's not clear to me which type the [one] would be from your interpretation. I guess what I'm asking is, is my interpretation **ever** possible, or is it just plain wrong?

Comment: @user3856370 seems impossible to me :/ I agree with Matti's interpretation.